# Give user feedback on EditTexts with limited InputType

Tags: android, android-edittext, feedback

I have an EditText with a restricted InputType, like this: 
`latEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);`

This only accepts float/double values.

So when a user tries to type characters that are not allowed, nothing happens.
**I would like to give the user feedback when that happens**. E.g. "only decimals allowed" in a toast.

---

My guess would have been to use `onTextChanged` and try to validate the input there, but I'm not sure that method would even be called with restricted input.

---

**EDIT**
I used the idea of M.Saad Lakhan's answer, removed the `setInputType` flags and solved it with this regex and the `setError` method:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (!s.toString().matches("[0-9]{1,13}(\\.[0-9]*)?"))
        {
            latEdit.setError(wrongInputWarning);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to give some custom feedback back to the user the best way to go is 1. use `addTextChangedListener` and put your logic there 2. use RxBinding https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to do that:

```
latEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

You need to addTextChangeListener on your edit text as follows:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       if (!s.matches("(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only digits and . are allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etNewPassword.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        textv.setText(s);
    }
});
```

In on text changed you have to apply checks according to your requirements

Comment: Give it a try and let me know if it works also if it works dont forget to mark my post as answer. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Unfortunately none of the 3 methods work for me, as the wrong input is stopped by the `setInputType` before it can even be processed. I guess I would have to rewrite my implementation to make it work with TextChangedListener

Comment: Buddy remove it from xml just make simple edittext and make everything here dynamically

Comment: Search for regular expression for your case where you allow numbers and one dot only and implement regular expression here and apply check if user input any other key it will show toast what you want :)

Comment: Here is your regex " (?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| ) "

Comment: I edited answer implement this. I dont checked it just try it if there are some errors try to remove but it will work, let me know if you need my assistance

Comment: Hope this works ... and remember I dont tested it but it will work there may be some minor changes required but you can do your work in this way

Comment: do update me if you have any questions. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Also check regex may be there is an error in mine one if you know how to make it then made urself otherwise just search it on web

Comment: After testing different ways of doing this I settled for something like your idea, just with a different regex since this one does not work

Comment: I m glad If I helped you mate

Answer (score 1):

Try using a pattern string and match it with the string from the text listener.
If the text does not matches the compiled pattern, then show some error message.

I had this similar problem like yours
hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

first add `android:inputType="number"` in your edittext xml. this will cause to open nummeric keyboard only. then
you need to add addOnTextChangedListner then in onTextChanged() you will get String data.

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after){

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count){
        String text = s.toString();
        try {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
            Log.i("", num + " is a number");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.i("", text + " is not a number");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){

    }
});
```